# Custom API within Azure Mobile Services. response.send sometimes returns results, sometimes not. (documented code inside)

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I wrote a custom API that searches an SQL table via Azure Mobile Services when called from my iOS app. The table is populated with zip codes with accompanying latitude and longitude coordinates. Given a search proximity, the algorithm will find all zip codes within the proximity of a specified zip code. It will then use these discovered zip codes to search an information table of entities and return any entity that contains a discovered zip code.

The problem that I am having is that my query is sometimes returning data, and sometimes it isn't. My zip code table has ~35,000 zip codes. I am able to perform operations on the zip code table without issue (insert, search, read....). The information table that the discovered zip codes are used to search only contains one item to test retrieval when the zip codes have been discovered. When querying the zip code table, it always returns data. When using the retrieved zip code data to query the information table, the test entity within may or may not be returned. The zip code table querying always works, information table querying sometimes doesn't, basically. I know that node.js is asynchronous, but I have been at this for days and have revised my code many times. The code always reaches the return.send, so it is always finding the desired zip code in the zip code table.

Here is my code. I have documented it so that you can inspect it easier.

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {

var postal = request.body.Postal;
var proximity = request.body.Proximity;

var countryGeoTable;   
var geoQuery; 
if(request.body.Country == "United States")
{
    //first the table of zip codes is retrieved.
    countryGeoTable = request.service.tables.getTable('UnitedStatesGeoLocations');
    //a query is prepared that finds the zip codes within the 
    //specified proximity of a zip code, then queries the information 
    //table with thise tip codes to find entities that have those zip codes.
    geoQuery = 'SELECT * FROM UnitedStatesEntities WHERE postal IN (SELECT postal FROM UnitedStatesGeoLocations WHERE latitude > ? AND latitude < ? AND longitude > ? AND longitude < ?)';
}

//the zip code entered is retrieved from the zip code table
countryGeoTable.where({ postal : postal}).read(
{
    success: function(results) 
    {
        if (results.length > 0)
        {
           //if the zip code is in the table, then using its longitude and latitude coordinates a
           //bounding box will be created, which will be used to find all zip codes within that
           //region. The proximity passed into the script determines the size of this bounding box.
            var postalLatitude = results[0].latitude;
            var postalLongitude = results[0].longitude;
            var lat1 = postalLatitude-(proximity/69);
            var lat2 = postalLatitude+(proximity/69);
            var lon1 = postalLongitude-proximity/Math.abs(Math.cos(proximity * Math.PI/180)*69);
            var lon2 = postalLongitude+proximity/Math.abs(Math.cos(proximity * Math.PI/180)*69);                

            //the nested SELECT query will first find the zip codes, then use them to find all
            //entities within the information table that has that zip code.
            request.service.mssql.query(geoQuery,[lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2],
            {
                success: function(entities) 
                {
                    //the problem here is that the entity may or may not be retrieved.
                    if(entities.length > 0)
                    {
                        //if retrieved, then the entity will be send to the client.
                        response.send(statusCodes.OK, entities);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.send(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND,{ error : "no entities found in proximity" });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            request.respond(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND, 'Zip Code Not Found!');
        }
    }
});
```

};

In finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361930/node-js-returning-result-from-mysql-query) post, I have revised my code to the following, but the same behavior persists.

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {

var postal = request.body.Postal;
var proximity = request.body.Proximity;

var countryGeoTable;   
var geoQuery; 
if(request.body.Country == "United States")
{
    countryGeoTable = request.service.tables.getTable('UnitedStatesGeoLocations');
    geoQuery = 'SELECT * FROM UnitedStatesEntities WHERE postal IN (SELECT postal FROM UnitedStatesGeoLocations WHERE latitude > ? AND latitude < ? AND longitude > ? AND longitude < ?)';
}

entityFinder(function(entities)
{
    if (entities.length > 0) 
    {
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, entities);
    }
    else
    {
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'no entities within this proximity' });
    }
});

function entityFinder(callback)
{
    getCoordinates(countryGeoTable,function(parameter) 
    {            
        request.service.mssql.query(geoQuery,parameter,
        {
            success: function(entities) 
            {
                callback(entities);
            }
        });
    });
}

function getCoordinates(countryGeoTable,callback)
{
    countryGeoTable.where({ postal : postal}).read(
    {
        success: function(results) 
        {
            if (results.length > 0)
            {                
                var postalLatitude = results[0].latitude;
                var postalLongitude = results[0].longitude;
                var lat1 = postalLatitude-(proximity/69);
                var lat2 = postalLatitude+(proximity/69);
                var lon1 = postalLongitude-proximity/Math.abs(Math.cos(proximity * Math.PI/180)*69);
                var lon2 = postalLongitude+proximity/Math.abs(Math.cos(proximity * Math.PI/180)*69);

                var parameter = [lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2];

                callback(parameter);              
            }
            else
            {
                request.respond(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND, 'Zip Code Not Found!');
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

};

Comment: What type of response are you getting when you have no results?  It's possible you are just hitting a timeout as your SQL queries are being slow.

Comment: No errors or anything within the Logs section. I can click the button within my app to invoke the API and will either get an empty container or a container with the data requested in it. The app doesn't crash, and the response time is immediate.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything jumping out at me with your code. Can you add a console.log(entities) in the success path and  then see what it is logged when you get an empty response?

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded sooner; I've been out all day. When I to a console log, i get just [] in the output. When I actually get data, then all of the data specified to be retrieved is in the report. I just did a test and in three queries, I got blank, then data on the second try, then blank on the third try. Each case the retrieval was finished in under a second. The blank reporting is intermittent. In one scenario I got 5 successes in a row, then one blank.

Comment: I tried using the first copy of your script and couldn't repro the issue. Are you using the same input params each time this happens?  (I see how a prox of 0 could cause issues.)  Its really odd that entities was [] but didn't go down your 404 path.  Perhaps the math function can produce a number that SQL doesn't like/interpret correctly?  Can you log the lat/lon vars and see if they are the same in the success & failure path.