# How to use callbacks in module.export function for mysql query - nodejs,express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, callback

I have the following code structure in `exports.js`

```
module.exports = {
    getData:function(param1,param2,callback){
        sql.query('SELECT users FROM table',function(error,result){
            callback(null,result[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

And I called it from main file `app.js` file like

```
var common = require('./exports');
console.log(common.getData(null,null));
```

I got the following error

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

However I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361930/node-js-returning-result-from-mysql-query). But didn't fixed the problem. Any help would be appreciated..!

Comment: You have this problem because callback is third argument of your function.. but when you call `getData(null, null, <callback here>)` you do not pass third argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getData()` accepts 3 arguments

The last of which should be a function which you have not provided in your example. Add a callback function in your call like so:

```
common.getData(null,null, function(err, result) {

    console.log(result)

});
```

The `sql.query` function uses the callback function you pass in as the third parameter and thats why your getting the error to say it's missing.

Comment: So I have to make a function to use the results right ? Is there a way to get only results without expanding a function like structure ?

Comment: For example consider this `function test() { return "response"; }` . When I call `test()` it will return `response` only. So I do not have to expand like ,let's say `test(function(res){ // further })`.

Comment: I've just updated my example. Yes you need to pass a function into `common.getData`. Thats the best way to handle the results.

Comment: Of course you can do what you've suggested in your comments but the thing about JavaScript is that if you have something thats happening Asynchronously  the your return statement might be called before the async tasks has finished and then then return value might be wrong. Your callback function is only called at a time when the async task is complete.

Comment: Then I will go with this :D

Answer (score 1):

if you want print results

```
var common = require('./exports');
common.getData(null, null, function(err, result){
    console.log(result)l
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Goolishka. But I can accept only one answer :)