# Async and await implement return failed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The caller function calls async function wcNam2Uid2 to return a name.
Then, caller console.log the return ( name).

The console.log is :

```
Enter nam2userid , input:Tommy Leung
 in main, resolve result : undefined
result id :tommyleung
nam2userid resolved , wc_id :  tommyleung  "
```

My main.js  is :

```
var express = require('express');


async function caller(snam) {
     //console.log(" main start with: "+ snam);
     const uid = await wcNam2Uid2(snam); 
     console.log(" in main, resolve result : " + uid);
  
    } 
let wcname ="Tommy Leung";
caller(wcname);
```

The code in function wcNam2Uid2

```
async function wcNam2Uid2(wcname )  
{
     //return data
 var myJson ="";
 var mysql = require('mysql');
 var fs = require('fs');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var mnam = wcname;
  console.log("Enter nam2userid , input:" + mnam );
      //wcname;
   var con = mysql.createConnection({
          host: "localhost",
          user: "root",
          password: "",  
          database: "crm"
         });
     // select leads by name
        con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.query("SELECT wc_id FROM wcdirlist where name = '" + mnam + "' ", function (err, result, fields) {
            setTimeout(() => { 
             if (err) throw err;
              
              console.log("result id :"+ result[0].wc_id);
              var wcid = result[0].wc_id;
              con.end;
              console.log(" nam2userid resolved , wc_id :  " + wcid);
            
             return wcid;            

            },2000);
       });
   });
 }
```

The excerpts from the ending is the concern, (above it is running.)

```
   console.log(" nam2userid resolved , wc_id :  " + wcid);
            
             return wcid;
```

As  you  may see the first line is good as it showed correctly in console.log,  but  the  next  line  "return  wcid"  failed.
The 2nd line in console.log where the response of function caller came out too soon is the problem, await is not doing, I suppose.

Comment: By the way `con.end;` does nothing, maybe you meant `con.end();`

Comment: *"the next line "return wcid" failed."*: what does that mean? The return surely didn't fail: it executed. But you cannot expect to output a *future* result already *now*.

Comment: What does wcNam2Uid2 return.  
return wcid is the return of anonymous callback fn inside con.connect. 
In such case that anonymous function will return  wcid but not  wcNam2Uid2. 
If you have not explicitly given return for wcNam2Uid2 it will return undefined.

Comment: @Akhil,I have included the whole codes of  function wcNam2Uid2 in the question on top , How and where do I return the wcid to caller?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the set timeout and do as you did on the first function, wrap the code on the async function and await the result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I studied inside stackflow and an article looked like the solution using callback. The Callback  link :
[Node.js returning result from MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361930/node-js-returning-result-from-mysql-query)

My codes  :

```
function getwcid(uname, callback)
{
    const mysql = require("mysql");
    
   const con = mysql.createConnection({
          host: "localhost",
          user: "root",
          password: "",  
          database: "crm"
         }); 
    
    
    con.query(  "SELECT wc_id FROM wcdirlist WHERE  name = '"+ uname +"'", function(err, result)
    {
        if (err) 
            callback(err,null);
        else
            callback(null,result[0].wc_id);

    });
 return
}

//call Fn for db query with callback
getwcid("Tommy Leung", function(err,data){
        if (err) {
            // error handling code goes here
            console.log("ERROR : ",err);            
        } else {            
            // code to execute on data retrieval
            console.log("result from db is : ",data);   
        }    

});
return;
```

The console.log :

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.embedder.node\node-v14.15.4-win-x64\node.exe test_getwcid_3.js 
result from db is :  tommyleung
```

The answer by callback is very simple and anyone has a shorter answer by await ?

Comment: what happens if you do it like this 
let result = await con.query("SELECT stateement");
console.log(result);
Will it work